# Can anyone help me with this code?

Tags: c, pointers

I think my logic is correct but it's not printing anything. The code is to eliminate the vowel from a string and then display it.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h> 
 void main()
  { 
   char *str="shivank"; 
   int i,len;
   char *q; 
   clrscr();  
   len=strlen(str);
    for(i=0;i<=len;i++)
     {   
        if((*str=='a')||(*str=='e')||(*str=='i')||(*str=='o')||(*str=='u')) 
           str++;     
        else if(*str=='\0')       
            break;   
        else   
          {      
            *q=*str;  
             str++;
             q++; 
          }
     }
     *q='\0';
     puts(q);  
     getch(); 
   }
```

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577) The [ask] page has tips for asking effective questions.

Comment: You need to allocate q so that it points to some memory.

Comment: `void main()` is wrong, `main` should return an `int`. `<conio.h>`, `clrscr()` and `getch()` are not part of the C language. C doesn't have magic strings that automatically grow in size as you access them, so `q` is not one of those. Always enable the highest level of warnings for your compiler and treat them as errors.

Comment: `q` has never been assigned/initialized.  So`*q` is attempting to de-reference an unknown value.  `q` needs assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to transform `"shivank"` into `"shvnk"`, and store it in a seperate string to print it later.

You have to allocate this memory somewhere. Just working with pointers won't do the work - at the very best, you could change `str` to point to a different beginning of the string: `"hivank"`, `"ivank"`, `"vank"` etc.. are all possible to get using only pointer arithmetics, but that's about it.

I would recommend you use `char` arrays instead of using string constants:

```
char str[] = "shivank";
char modified_str[10]; // enough memory to store the modified string
```

The advantage of using arrays is that you can modify them like this example:

```
modified_str[0] = str[0];
```

(this is just an example that copies the first letter of `str` into the first letter of `modified_str`)

Then you could read the characters of your `str` string one by one, and only copy the non-vowels to `modified_str`. Don't forget to end your `modified_str` by a '\0'.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
else   
      {      
        *q=*str;  
         puts(q);
         str++;
         q++; 
      }
 }
 *q='\0';
```

Comment: Why is this any better?

Comment: Because it prints q as you check through the string. Your original code prints q once whereas the way you have written the code, you need to print q as you check the string. Try it. I believe it will work.

Comment: `q` has never been assigned/initialized.  `*q` is UB.  `puts(q);` is too late to help in any way.  Unless `q` has a valid value, `puts(q);` itself is UB too.

Comment: Ya I got it puts(q) will print from '/0' .that's why it's not printing anything.there should be  another pointer that will be pointing to start of q.